# Gdalwarp dstnodata problems

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm trying to change the values of nodata from my source file to a set value for my output file, but all I am getting is an error.
This is my code:

```
    from osgeo import gdal
    from subprocess import call

    input_raster = r"c:\blah\someinputtiff.tif" #This file I want to clip

    output_raster = r"c:\blah\someoutputtiff.tif" #The resulting clip file

    input_shape = r"c:\blah\someshapefile.shp" #The file I want to use to clip the.tif

    call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe','-
    dstNodata"value[-9999]"', '-cutline' , input_shape , '-crop_to_cutline' ,  
    input_raster , output_raster, '-overwrite'])
```

This produces the following error:

```
    FAILURE: Unknown option name '-dstNodata"value[-9999]"'
```

I have tried multiple permutations of '-dstNodata' followed by a value but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since GDAL 2.1 it's possible to use [GDAL/OGR utilities as library functions](http://erouault.blogspot.it/2015/10/gdal-and-ogr-utilities-as-library.html). So this is an alternative way to accomplish this task:

```
from osgeo import gdal

input_raster = r"c:\blah\someinputtiff.tif" #This file I want to clip
output_raster = r"c:\blah\someoutputtiff.tif" #The resulting clip file
input_shape = r"c:\blah\someshapefile.shp" #The file I want to use to clip the.tif

ds = gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_raster, format = 'GTiff', cutlineDSName = input_shape, cutlineLayer = 'someshapefile', dstNodata = -9999)
ds = None
```

Comment: Similarly to the question, in my case the lack of 'dstNodata' parameter usage set all the nodata values to 0, which had an affect in histograms etc. By using -9999, now it shows 'no data' in QGIS. But I don't know the exact values, since I can't create a human readable ASCII Grid' format :/

Answer (score 1):

From `gdalwarp` [documentation page](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html):

> **-dstnodata value [value...]:**
>
> Set nodata values for output bands (different values can be supplied for each band). If more than one
>   value is supplied all values should be quoted to keep them together as
>   a single operating system argument. New files will be initialized to
>   this value and if possible the nodata value will be recorded in the
>   output file. Use a value of None to ensure that nodata is not defined
>   (GDAL>=1.11). If this argument is not used then nodata values will be
>   copied from the source dataset (GDAL>=1.11).

Examples from `gdalwarp` [wiki page](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) ignoring a single value for one or more bands and different values per band:

```
# for this image we want to ignore black (0)
gdalwarp -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 orig-ignore-black.tif black-nodata.tif

# and now we want to ignore white (0)
gdalwarp -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata 255 orig-ignore-white.tif white-nodata.tif

# and finally ignore a particular blue-grey (RGB 125 125 150)
gdalwarp -srcnodata "125 125 150" -dstnodata "125 125 150" orig-ignore-grey.tif grey-nodata.tif

# now we can mosaic them all and not worry about nodata parameters
gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 black-nodata.tif grey-nodata.tif white-nodata.tif final-mosaic.tif
```

Based in this information, I think that your error raises for two reasons, value definition (`"value[-9999]"`) and the space between the option name and the option value (`-dstNodata"value[-9999]"`).

So, my recommendation is to change to:

```
call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe','-
    dstnodata -9999', '-cutline' , input_shape , '-crop_to_cutline' ,  
    input_raster , output_raster, '-overwrite'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this didn't work and the error simply changed to: FAILURE: Unknown option name '-dstNodata -9999'

Comment: I made the same mistake than yours.... The option is `-dstnodata`, not `-dstNodata`

Comment: FAILURE: Unknown option name '-dstnodata -9999'
Still no luck, I have no idea why it's refusing to accept this as an option...

Comment: @Yjelza, also are you sure you're using gdal>=1.11? from python try calling
>>> gdal.__version__

Comment: @dr_times I'm definitely using Gdal 2.2.2

Comment: @aldo_tapia I'm only calling the module in python because I forgot to comment it out!

Comment: Instead, my recommendation is:
`call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalwarp.exe','-dstnodata', '-9999', '-cutline', input_shape, '-crop_to_cutline', input_raster, output_raster, '-overwrite'])`